# Arrange plots with ggarrange(): How to change the size of y-axis label and add a title (customization)

Tags: r, ggplot2, aes

I use ggarrange() to put together 4 plots with a common legend (different datasets, which is why I use ggarrange() instead of other functions).

Unfortunately, the y-axis labels overlap and I couldn't find out how to add a title or other customizations.

```
plot_velocity_uni <- ggplot() +
  xlim(c(0, 200)) +
  stat_function(fun = fun.1, aes(color = "Left atrium")) +
  geom_function(fun = fun.2, aes(color = "Left ventricle")) +
  geom_function(fun = fun.3, aes(color = "Right atrium")) +
  geom_function(fun = fun.4, aes(color = "Right ventricle")) +
  xlab("heart rate")+ # for the x axis label
  ylab("estimated unipolar conduction velocity (m/s)")+ # for the y axis label
  theme(legend.position = "none", aspect.ratio = 1)

plot_velocity_bi <- ggplot() +
  xlim(c(0, 200)) +
  stat_function(fun = fun.1, aes(color = "Left atrium")) +
  geom_function(fun = fun.2, aes(color = "Left ventricle")) +
  geom_function(fun = fun.3, aes(color = "Right atrium")) +
  geom_function(fun = fun.4, aes(color = "Right ventricle"))+
  xlab("heart rate")+ # for the x axis label
  ylab("estimated bipolar conduction velocity (m/s)")+ # for the y axis label
  theme(legend.position = "none", aspect.ratio = 1)

plot_voltage_uni <- ggplot() +
  xlim(c(0, 200)) +
  stat_function(fun = fun.1, aes(color = "Left atrium")) +
  geom_function(fun = fun.2, aes(color = "Left ventricle")) +
  geom_function(fun = fun.3, aes(color = "Right atrium")) +
  geom_function(fun = fun.4, aes(color = "Right ventricle")) +
  xlab("heart rate")+ # for the x axis label
  ylab("estimated unipolar conduction velocity (m/s)")+ # for the y axis label
  theme(legend.position = "none", aspect.ratio = 1)

plot_voltage_bi <- ggplot() +
  xlim(c(0, 200)) +
  stat_function(fun = fun.1.bi, aes(color = "Left atrium")) +
  geom_function(fun = fun.2.bi, aes(color = "Left ventricle")) +
  geom_function(fun = fun.3.bi, aes(color = "Right atrium")) +
  geom_function(fun = fun.4.bi, aes(color = "Right ventricle")) +
  xlab("heart rate")+ # for the x axis label
  ylab("estimated unipolar conduction velocity (m/s)")+ # for the y axis label
  theme(legend.position = "none", aspect.ratio = 1)

ggarrange(plot_velocity_uni, plot_velocity_bi, plot_voltage_uni, plot_voltage_bi, ncol=2, nrow=2, common.legend = TRUE, legend="right", labels = c("A", "B", "C", "D"))
```

[image]

Comment: What result do you want? Perhaps more vertical space between charts? Smaller font size on the y-axis labels? Y-axis labels on two rows?

Comment: Both ideas are good. How could I do that?
But I think I prefer the font size solution

Comment: For changing the labels (including making the font size smaller or making the text wrap), you'll want to try something for each of the individual plots, prior to ggarrange. But, I'd really recommend that you reconsider the text of your y-axis label, they are really too long . Why not just "Bipolar Conduction (m/s)" or "Unipolar Conduction (m/s)". Nobody wants to read long rotated text. Put the context in the title or a footnote.